# Link-widget GWT - uiBinder

Tags: gwt, hyperlink, uibinder

I want to use a link or a button like (a href="..."/>) in GWT with uiBinder.

I found the widget "hyperlink" but I don´t know how I use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [Anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) widget.

You can use a sample ClickHandler on it to detect the click event or use the default href with the constructor :

```
Anchor(boolean useDefaultHref)
```

You can also use the setter [setHref(java.lang.String href)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html#setHref%28java.lang.String%29)

In UiBinder :

```
<g:Anchor ui:field="mylink" href="/myurl">The link test</g:Anchor>
```

EDIT :

To open the link in a new tab, you should use the [setTarget(String target)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html#setTarget%28java.lang.String%29) method like the following example :

```
setTarget("_blank");
```

Comment: thanks...
but when i tried it: anchor.setHref("www.google.at");
then it opens 127.0.0.1:8888/www.google.at

and I want to open that in a new tab. How does this work?

Comment: I edited my answer ;) If it's good, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: ok. thanks...
but my first question? when i tried it: anchor.setHref("www.google.at"); then it opens 127.0.0.1:8888/www.google.at

Comment: ok. thanks... but my first question? when i tried it: anchor.setHref("www.google.at"); then it opens 127.0.0.1:8888/www.google.at

Comment: Read my answer. Use the setTarget method to "_blank" to open www.google.at without 127.0.0.1:8888/....

Comment: "www.google.at" is missing the "http://" part. Otherwise it will be interpreted as a URL relative to the domain root.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to programatically do things with the anchor,  you can just add the html into the uibinder code directly.   In fact, UIBinder is not just a WYSIWYG, but it is a place for you to enter as much native HTML as you can.  That makes for leaner and faster web apps.